# Java extract exif (metadata) from jpg image

Tags: java, metadata, exif

Does anyone know any class which allows extracting metadata in java from .jpg image? Or maybe some useful code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a library that does exactly this.

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/

The API is pretty simple:

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imagePath);
```